# Show that there exists $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum\limits_{n\leq x}\frac{\sin(\log n)}{n} = -\cos(\log x) + c + O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove the statement in the title, i.e., that there exists a real constant $c$ such that

$$\sum\limits_{n\leq x}{\frac{\sin{\left(\log{n}\right)}}{n}} = -\cos{\left(\log{x}\right)} + c + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

for all $x\geq 1$.

Posing $f(x) = \frac{\sin(\log x)}{x}$ and using the Euler-Maclaurin formula one gets:

$$\sum\limits_{n\leq x}{\frac{\sin{\left(\log{n}\right)}}{n}} = -\cos{\left(\log{x}\right)} + 1 + \left\lbrace x\right\rbrace f\left(x\right) + \int_{1}^{x}{\left\lbrace t\right\rbrace f'\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}$$

Much like one does to define the Euler-Mascheroni constant, I can define $c := 1 - \int_{1}^{\infty}{\left\lbrace t\right\rbrace f'\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}$ and bound the $\left\lbrace x\right\rbrace f\left(x\right)$ and $\int_{x}^{\infty}{\left\lbrace t\right\rbrace f'\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}$ terms by $\frac{1}{x}$, but I have trouble with this last part, as $f'\left(x\right)$ is a bit weird and I cannot quite prove that the improper integral converges since it sometimes dip below zero and pops back up.

I would appreciate some help proving that last statement, or some other approach to obtain my final solution.

Comment: Looks easy to me: $$
\left| {\left\{ t \right\}f'(t)} \right| = \left| {\left\{ t \right\}\frac{{\cos (\log t) - \sin (\log t)}}{{t^2 }}} \right| \le \frac{2}{{t^2 }}.
$$

Comment: I forgot about the property thanks. I'm a bit slow today.